# Loading texture doesn't work with the correct texture width/height

Tags: java, image, opengl-es, textures, image-formats

I am trying to load a texture for a cube and I have trouble with the dimensions I use. The texture has the power of two (256x256). When it should use 256 as width and height it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Required 262144 remaining bytes in buffer, only had 68998
    at com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers.rangeCheckBytes(Buffers.java:828)
```

The code:

```
private void initTexture(GL2ES2 gl) {
try {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new URI("http://192.168.0.39/images/box.gif").toURL());
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "gif", byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imageData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageData);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
imageBuffer.rewind();
gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIds[0]);
gl.glTexImage2D(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2ES2.GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL2ES2.GL_RGBA, GL2ES2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuffer);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2ES2.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2ES2.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
gl.glGenerateMipmap(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glBindTexture(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

When I change the parameter width/height to 128 the exception disappears but the cubes show wrong colors:

[image]

As bestsss mentioned, the reason might be some raw format. The problem: I can't fix this. I tried multiple images and formats. Created them with gimp (working on ubuntu) but the exception is always the same. So I guess the reason for that is that I read the image in a wrong way. Some ideas?

**Update**

My solution (which uses JOGL classes TextureIO and Texture):

```
Texture texture;

private void initTexture(GL2ES2 gl) {
    try {
        texture = TextureIO.newTexture(new URI("http://192.168.0.39/images/box.gif").toURL(),true,null);
        texture.setTexParameterf(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2ES2.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        texture.setTexParameterf(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2ES2.GL_LINEAR);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void display(GL2ES2 gl) {
    // code snipped
    if (texture != null) {
        texture.enable();
        texture.bind();
    }
    // code snipped
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero clue about the API however. I can bet the expected format is some raw one **NOT gif** since 262144 =2^18 (or 256*256*4). RGB+Alpha are 4bytes.

edit: again, 
`gl.glTexImage2D(GL2ES2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2ES2.GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL2ES2.GL_RGBA, GL2ES2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuffer);`

just guessting but look at the constants: GL2ES2.GL_RGBA, GL2ES2.GL_RGBA, GL2ES2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE - all support RGBA format for the bytes in the byte buffer,see what other contestants are available, the way I believe using NIO would have point only with *direct* buffers containing the raster in the format specified by the constants. (i.e. no other formats for image storage/transmission like jpeg/bif/png will help)

So read the documentation again, look for tutorial, examples and proceed (the way you load the image is not very good either)

Comment: Ok somehow my image reading must be wrong, because I tried multiple different images, image types, but its always the same. Some ideas?

Comment: If I had found a tutorial I wouldn't have asked... Could you please provide a better solution? Or a tutorial you would recommend? Just saying "the way you load the image is not very good" doesn't really help me (because thats the way I found in multiple "tutorials") I am not asking you to code me the solution, but providing a bit more detailed help would be very nice

Comment: Fine :) I'd have a deeper look tonight. I'd not recommend you loading anything from http like that, trapping the exception and continuing w/ a possibly non-initialized imageBuffer , which is not even local variable. The buffer, itself, is heap one and as much as I see you use native API, so odds are they need direct buffers.

Comment: Sorry for being rude, I am a bit under time pressure :/

Comment: No, need to feel sorry; no offense taken and I'd not even think of you being rude

Comment: Ok after reading a lot and making all worse, I got a working solution which uses JOGL (in this case I stopped using native calls...) anyway thanks for your patience...

Comment: I was going to drop some code how to do it w/ raw format. you need: BufferedImage().getData().getPixels() and use ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer().put() to convert